# Can't remove mongod.lock

Tags: linux, mongodb, read-only, remove

all.

I want to remove `mongod.lock`. When I try `sudo rm -rf mongod.lock` I got this

```
rm: cannot remove ‘mongod.lock’: Read-only file system
```

Can anyone tell me how to force remove it?

Thanks,
Ami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm: cannot remove ‘mongod.lock’: Read-only file system
```

Your filesystem has been mounted read-only. You cannot remove files from a read-only filesystem.

So your next task will be to determine why your filesystem is read-only. The kernel typically will remount the filesystem as read-only in response to significant filesystem corruption or other storage issues such as very high latency.

Comment: Yup, you're right. It turns out there was sudden restart from my database so linux automatically change the drive to read-only to protect it from further disk error. We end up changing the disk.